# Select by letters

Tags: php, mysql

I've database with many entries
and i would like to call for example 10 entries that starts with letter A

for example

```
$qry="select * from table where entery STARTS WITH "A" order by RAND() LIMIT 10";
```

How to do it !

Thanks

Comment: First of all, fix your quotes :)

Comment: @Reanimation Because you can't always assume it was a typo initially. I have scratched my head over problems which didn't work simply because I corrected the spelling without checking if it was initially spelt like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE entery LIKE 'A%' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10";
```

The % sign is a kind of wildcard. Here you get [further informations about the LIKE function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/string-comparison-functions.html).

Comment: +1 to counter ThiefMaster...-1 for typo..really? why don't you edit it yourself, cuz that's why you have those privs...

Comment: I have edited it simultaneously with ThiefMaster. What do you mean with -1 for typo?

Comment: ThiefMaster downvoted you because of your typo. So I upvoted to counter it because it's a stupid thing to downvote someone for, esp when people (like him) can just edit it.

Comment: Yes, he downvoted you because of the double quotes instead of single quotes, and then made a comment along the lines of "-1 for quotes".  But he has deleted his comment and maybe even removed his downvote idk.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for:

```
 WHERE entery LIKE 'A%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the substring() function

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

Eg :

```
select * from table where SUBSTRING(columnname, 1, 1) = 'a';
```

You may also achieve this using `LIKE 'A%'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
    $qry="SELECT * FROM table WHERE entery LIKE 'A%' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "select * from table where entry like 'A%' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10";
```

Answer (score 0):

$qry="SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE entery LIKE A%
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 10";